# RewriteRule correction

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've been working on this for whole day but I can't figure it out. This is what I want. Both should have URLs left as `/p/test/` or `/p/test` and not actually redirect to `/p.php?slug=test` (same with tag).

```
example.com/p/test/ -> Do query example.com/p.php?slug=test  
example.com/p/test  -> Do query example.com/p.php?slug=test

example.com/tag/sometag/ -> Do query example.com/tag/index.php?tagID=sometag  
example.com/tag/sometag  -> Do query example.com/tag/index.php?tagID=sometag
```

What I've tried so far:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^p/([a-z]+)$ p/$1/ [L]
RewriteRule ^p/([a-z]+)/$ p.php?slug=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^tag/([a-z]+)/?$ tag/index.php?tagID=$2 [L]
```

2nd example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^p/([a-z]+)$ p/$1/ [L]
RewriteRule ^p/([a-z]+)/$ p.php?slug=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^tag/([a-z]+)$ tag/$2/ [L]
RewriteRule ^tag/([a-z]+)/$ /tag/index.php?tagID=$2/ [L]
```

Last example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^p/([.*])$ p/$1/ [L]
RewriteRule ^p/([.*])/$ p.php?slug=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^tag/([.*])/?$ tag/index.php?tagID=$1 [L]
```

Non of them working fine except first example first rule (line 3 and 4). Even that one had a problem, the /p/test is different with /p/test/ but there were no sign of error whatsoever.

Here is the function for proceeding tagID param (and it works fine):

```
public function searchTagID($tag) {
    if (isset($tag)) {
        $db     = new databaseEstablish();
        $con    = $db->connect();

        $sql    = $db->dbQuery($con, "SELECT *
                                      FROM posts
                                      WHERE tags LIKE '%{$tag}%'");

        $resultCount = $db->countRows($sql);

        if ($resultCount == 0) {
            Header('Location: ../../index.php');
        }
        while($row = $db->fetchArray($sql)){
                echo $row[0];
            }
    }
}
```

---

This .htaccess bellow:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^tag/([^/]+)/?$ /tag/index.php?tagID=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^p/([^/]+)/?$ /p.php?slug=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Redirects example.com/p/test/ -> example.com/p.php?slug=test
Redirects example.com/p/test  -> Object not found error

Redirects example.com/tag/sometag/ -> Object not found error 
Redirects example.com/tag/sometag  -> Object not found error

Now, there is something I wanted to tell you, please don't blame me, but I don't want above URLs to redirect to that page I wrote at the top, but just to rewrite them (Do query). For example: `example.com/p/test/` -> SHOULD NOT REDIRECT TO `example.com/p.php?slug=test` BUT ONLY DO THAT URL QUERY (in how can I call it back-end). URL SHOULD STILL BE `example.com/p/test/` (or /p/test). Can't explain it better, really.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?p/([^/]+)/?$ /p.php?slug=$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?tag/([^/]+)/?$ /tag/index.php?tagID=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /projects/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^tag/([^/]+)/?$ tag/index.php?tagID=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^p/([^/]+)/?$ p.php?slug=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Nop. That didn't work, browser displays Object not found error. Removing the slash infront of /p & /tag makes it a slightly better (No error but slash at the end and no slash shows up different page. Any other ideas?

Comment: What URL did you use to test it? What is location of this .htaccess and are there more rules?

Comment: I've used both `example.com/post/test/` (and `/post/test`) and `example.com/tag/sometag/` (and `/tag/sometag`). Check the edit of the post (bellow last line) what I've have so far.

Comment: I thought it was `/p/` instead of `/post/` Is this some CMS/PHP framework?

Comment: ok got it. Are `/p/` or `/tag/` real directories by any chance and are there more rules in it?

Comment: Oh.. That could be a problem. There is both `/p/` and `/tag/` directory. The `/p/` directory is having posts (test.php [actually testtest.php but whatever]) while `/tag/` directory only have index.php (which is used for tag searching that I'm calling [`/tag/index.php?tagID=#`]). Other then that, I have to use `p.php` which is in root directory and not `/p/` directory. Here is a picture for better understanding: [pic](http://i.imgur.com/8CgmSSj.png) Also, as you can see, .htaccess is in root directory too.

Comment: ok but there is no additional .htaccess in `/p` and in `/tag` right?

Comment: Didn't work. That directive even made it worse then it is. Now when I click on hyperlink for showing posts it redirects me to `http://127.0.0.1/p.php?slug=testtest` instead of `http://127.0.0.1/projects/cblogphp2/p.php?slug=testtest`. So, a few  (two) dirs back.

Comment: Did you ever mention that there is a `/projects/` directory also?

Comment: I did not to be honest. Damn.

Comment: Should I add cblohphp2 directory to the rewritebase or?

Comment: Yes make it `RewriteBase /projects/cblohphp2` any reason why gave half correct information in question?

Comment: Sorry for late answer. It is as above, `http://127.0.0.1/projects/cblogphp2/p/testtest/` redirects to `http://127.0.0.1/p.php?slug=testest`, and `http://127.0.0.1/projects/cblogphp2/p/testtest` redirects to `http://127.0.0.1/projects/cblogphp2/p.php?slug=testtest` (ok) EDIT: fixed css.

Comment: broken css is due to your use of relative links in css. use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.
   You can try adding this in your page's HTML header: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: CSS fixed for showing post. Now it only up to slash `/` at the end. /p/testtest/ redirects few dirs bellow as in above comment and /tag/sometag works fine, no broken CSS, but /tag/sometag/ shows page with broken CSS. Also, to answer on your question "half correct information" I was sleep deprived. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: You've written a fairly long question in sleep deprived state so it only helps you if you provide all correct information. My suggested rules take care of all trailing slashes pretty well and absolute css links never fail slash or no slash. Paste your latest .htaccess and tell me which css link gives 404.